# Service domain name resolution not reliable

Tags: kubernetes

This is Kubernetes service

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysvc

spec:
  clusterIP: None
  
  selector:
    app: myapp
    type: main

  ports:
    - name: http
      appProtocol: http
      targetPort: http
      port: 8000
```

that serves 9 pods. Most of the time `mysvc.default.svc.cluster.local` resolves into 9 IP addresses. Randomly it resolves into 8 IP addresses (one IP address disappears) while pods stay the same and healthy. Pods are located on separate nodes that are located on multiple continents. There are 20 CoreDNS instances that are equally distributed on each node.

Is it possible to solve this issue?

Self-hosted Kubernetes 1.25.3

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the issue was not related to CoreDNS. Pods became not ready for a short period of time. It happened because one of the pod containers was a bash script that was **routinely exiting and starting again**. Restart happened really fast but that was enough time for the restarting pod to get removed from CoreDNS domain resolution response.